# I live in Beijing and I live in Beijing now?

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-simple

I'm learning English about present simple tense. I wonder if the "now" can be added to the present simple tense and change meaning.

I live in Beijing (relative permanently?). I live in Beijing Now (Before I lived in somewhere else, but recently moved to Beijing and continue to live in Beijing?)

Comment: Yes. "I live in Beijing now, but I used to live in Shanghai" or "...but I shall be moving to Shanghai next month".

Comment: Also fine to qualify "I live in Beijing" with "at the moment", "temporarily", "till (some time)", etc.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that "*I live in Beijing*" means conclusively that you have always lived there, or that you live there 'permanently'. What it really means is that the timing of when you began to live there, or how permanent it may be *is not relevant to your statement*.

By adding "now" you can suggest that you did not always live there, or with a different emphasis on the word you could imply that you perhaps may be moving in the future.